# How to get conditional values into new column from several external lists or arrays

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = [ {'id':  3, 'ratio': 1.3 ,'vol1': 100 }, 
      {'id':  5, 'ratio': 0.3 ,'vol1': 200 },
      {'id':  1, 'ratio': 1.1 ,'vol1': 300 },
      {'id':  8, 'ratio': 0.8 ,'vol1': 400 },
      {'id':  2, 'ratio': 2.0 ,'vol1': 500 },
      {'id':  4, 'ratio': 0.0 ,'vol1': 600 }
    ] 
data = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

To which I have to create an additional column `new_col_cond` that is dependent on the values of multiple external lists/arrays (I have also tried with dictionaries), for example:

```
q1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
q1_n = np.array(q1).reshape(-1)     #numpy array from above
q2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
q2_n = np.array(q2).reshape(-1)
```

The new column depends on the value of `ratio` and selects from either array according to `id` as index. I have tried:

```
data = data.withColumn('new_col_cond', when(col('ratio')<1, q1[col('id')])
                                      .when(col('ratio')>1, q2[col('id')])
                      ) #also with numpy arrays.
```

with errors coming. I assume that the main source of error is using a column as index for the array, but not sure how else to insert the index into the array. Given the conditional nature of the column I have not tried to ***join*** (data is millions of rows and lists are in the thousands).

Due to the size of the dataset I am steering away from Pandas and udfs. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
+---+-----+----+------------+
| id|ratio|vol1|new_col_cond|
+---+-----+----+------------+
|  3|  1.3| 100| 4          |
|  5|  0.3| 200| 60         |
|  1|  1.1| 300| 2          |
|  8|  0.8| 400| 90         |
|  2|  2.0| 500| 3          |
|  4|  0.0| 600| 50         |
+---+-----+----+------------+
```

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ArrayType column expressions from the numpy arrays and use them in your condition like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

q1_n = F.array(*[F.lit(int(x)) for x in q1_n])
q2_n = F.array(*[F.lit(int(x)) for x in q2_n])

result = data.withColumn(
    'new_col_cond',
    F.when(F.col('ratio') < 1, q1_n[F.col('id')])
        .when(F.col('ratio') > 1, q2_n[F.col('id')])
)

result.show()
#+---+-----+----+------------+
#| id|ratio|vol1|new_col_cond|
#+---+-----+----+------------+
#|  3|  1.3| 100|           4|
#|  5|  0.3| 200|          60|
#|  1|  1.1| 300|           2|
#|  8|  0.8| 400|          90|
#|  2|  2.0| 500|           3|
#|  4|  0.0| 600|          50|
#+---+-----+----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to add the 'new_col_cond' into your dictionaries **before** creating your dataframe.

```
d = [{'id':  3, 'ratio': 1.3, 'vol1': 100},
     {'id':  5, 'ratio': 0.3, 'vol1': 200},
     {'id':  1, 'ratio': 1.1, 'vol1': 300},
     {'id':  8, 'ratio': 0.8, 'vol1': 400},
     {'id':  2, 'ratio': 2.0, 'vol1': 500},
     {'id':  4, 'ratio': 0.0, 'vol1': 600}
     ]
q1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
q2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for d_ in d:
    d_['new_col_cond'] = q1[d_['id']] if d_['ratio'] < 1 else q2[d_['id']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

**Note:**

Whilst this will work for the data you've shown, I'm not sure if it's robust. If the 'id' key has a value >8, this will fail

Comment: thank you for your response, I can see this working for this example. The issue I face is that DF (data in the question) is a pre-existing parquet dataframe with millions of rows; although simple, not sure if it feasible.